# Thingsboard - - get a list of devices linked to an Assets

Tags: thingsboard

How to get a list of devices linked to an Asset through REST API?.

Swagger APIs

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It should be right there in the Swagger API?

https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html#!/entity-relation-controller/findInfoByToUsingGET

You provide inputs for the `toTarget`, and it returns all entities related **to** that target. Then, just filter the result for:

```
from.entityType === "DEVICE"
```